# Processing GTAG command: ["event", "purchase", ..] not received in GA4 Magento 2.4

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, magento2.4

We've set up GA4 in our magento 2.4.5 store.

Looking with GA Debug in our succes page, we've a purchase event triggered and sent :

Processing GTAG command: ["event", "purchase", {transaction_id: "000010768", affiliation: "Médipost", value: "6.09", tax: "1.06", shipping: "0.00", items: [{item_id: "BB-054-JU21-014", item_name: "Seni Happy Lange bébé Taille 5 Junior 12 à 25kg", price: "5.03", quantity: 1}]}]

However, there is 0 reccord of a purchase event inside GA4.

Can someone help ?

Thank you very much

We have configured Google tag manager in magento 2.4 via extension and want to fetch order details in analytics against each successful order. we have performed all the necessary configuration and tag manager is able to fetch the details for each step as shown below. However, when a particular order is placed, it is not recorded and visible in Google Analytics or tag manager.